# To end all videos with same class

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have following code to reset video:

```
var clicked_video = $('.video').get(0);
clicked_video.currentTime = clicked_video.seekable.end(0);
```

But I have multiple videos so I tried

```
var clicked_video = $('.video').get();
$(clicked_video).each(function( index, value ) {
    value.currentTime = value.seekable.end(0);
});
```

this one is not working

Comment: Have you checked the code itself works? I get an error when running it: `Failed to execute 'end' on 'TimeRanges': The index provided (0) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (0)`

Comment: yes first one is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `forEach()` method of the Array:

```
var clicked_video = $('.video').get();
clicked_video.forEach(function( videoElement ) {
    videoElement.currentTime = videoElement.seekable.end(0);
});
```